# How do I get my dockerized typescript node app working?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
# Download the slim version of node
FROM node:21-slim

# Set the work directory to app folder. 
# We will be copying our code here
WORKDIR /src

#Copy package.json file in the node folder inside container
COPY package.json .

# Copy the rest of the code in the container
COPY . .

# Install the dependencies in the container
RUN npm install

# Run the node server with server.js file
CMD ["npm", "start"]

# Expose the service over PORT 5000
EXPOSE 5000
```

Here is my package.json starting command :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -w src --ext ts --exec ts-node --esm src/app.ts"
  },
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  node_app:
    build: ./node
    container_name: node
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=5000
    command: sh -c "npm start"
    volumes:
      - ./node:/home/node/app:cached
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
```

And here is my file structure in vscode :
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEDyo.png)

And when I'm running docker inside this project with `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`, I'm getting the `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /src/src/app.ts` error.

I'm sure I'm missing something around docker and app paths but I didn't managed to find what.

Comment: side question: why explicitly first copy package.json if you then immediately also copy everything, which includes package.json? That said, `docker exec -it <yourdockervolumename> bash` into your docker volume so you can poke around.

Comment: Good question. There is no real explanation to this :).

Comment: This is what I've called "starting command" in my post, let me fix this

Comment: First guess: look at that filepath. You first enter `src` with that nodemon command, then you run `src/app.ts` inside of that. So it's probably not that "ts is an unknown extension", it's almost certainly "you don't have a src/src dir". So: bash into your container, and try to run your commands manually, one by one (not using npm start)

Comment: It was my first guess as well, let's give it a new try.

Comment: It seems that it is not related to the path because when I'm going inside the docker container in terminal, the paths are fine but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: but when I'm running the server directly through ts-node by bypassing nodemon and using the exact same path than the nodemon one, there is no problem...

Comment: This is sick, when I remove the `--esm` param from the `nodemon` command, it seems to work fine :/

Comment: Ah, makes sense I guess: TypeScript is not JavaScript, so your files can't be ESM (which is a JS format).

Comment: The path the Compose file and the comments are leading seems to be headed towards a path where you're principally running host code; everything in the image build gets ignored and overwritten with host content.  Would it be more convenient to use Node without Docker here?  Or are you looking for a path to run the container in a fully-isolated environment, without any dependencies on the host system at all?